# What is the grammar for "it mistakenly believed" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

I just find a sentence in NYTimes quite uncomfortable even though it reads quite smooth and articulate. I never saw that kind of sentence structure as following.

> By putting off repairs that **it mistakenly believed** were not critical, Amtrak set the stage for two of the derailments.

Can anyone help me explain the role of "**it mistakenly believed**"?
Thanks.

Comment: *It* refers forward to Amtrak. Does substituting Amtrak for the *it* clarify things for you?

Comment: It doesn't have a single role. It's the subject _it_ (meaning _Amtrak_), and adverb _mistakenly_, and main verb _believed_ of the clause _[it mistakenly believed] (that the repairs) were not critical_. [it mistakenly believed] is not a constituent, but a connected piece of the beginning of a Verb Phrase constituent, and therefore there isn't a special name for it.

Answer (score 1):

> it mistakenly believed

***It*** = A subject, later referred to in the sentence by its proper name, Amtrak.

***Mistakenly*** = The adverb form of 'Mistaken'.

***Believed*** = The verb 'believe', in past tense.

The structure subject-adverb-verb is pretty grammatically common in English.

Comment: Further, "mistakenly" modified "believed", indicating that the belief was in error.

Comment: The question is not about the words in the phrase, but rather it's about the role of the phrase in the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

*It mistakenly believed* is part of the clause *that it mistakenly believed were not critical.*  This clause modifies "repairs," so it tells us that Amtrak believed the repairs were not critical and that Amtrak was wrong to believe that.  The rest of the sentence tells us that Amtrak delayed the repairs (by implication because of this mistaken belief) and that this delay contributed to two derailments.